# How to write into different tables when rails model has been inherited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base;end

class Department < Building;end

class Organization < Building;end
```

When I create department and organization and get all departments

```
2.1.5 :008 > Department.all.count
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "buildings"
=> 2
```

I would like to get in this case

```
2.1.5 :008 > Department.all.count
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "departments"
=> 1 

2.1.5 :008 > Organization.all.count
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "organizations"
=> 1

2.1.5 :008 > Buildings.all.count
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "buildings"
=> 2
```

How I can do that?

Comment: inheritance in rails creates something called single table inheritance: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: I would argue this is not something you would want to do.  @Anthony is putting you on the right track with Single Table Inheritance (STI)

Comment: in other words, when you inherit you aren't creating multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use STI. Have a table called buildings with a column called 'type'. Have the new classes extend Building class. Each class can optionally have their own different relationships. You will be able to instantiate Building and get the class defined by the type or instantiate the desired class directly.

Comment: Thank you now I see my question was not clearly! I need to that by using 'type'